# Get specific value from gridview without dataformatstring

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When i BoundField i need to put a specific datafromatstring `dataformatstring="{0:###,###}"`

Later i want to get that values from gridView and when i get it i have strange format so i HTMLDecode it and then i get a values like 450 000 but i cant remove that space from this value.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "Summary:";

        for (int j = 1; j < grid_summary.Columns.Count; ++j)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid_summary.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (!grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Equals("&nbsp;"))
            {
                string columnValueDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
                columnValueDecode.Replace(" ", "");
                columnValueDecode.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
                columnValueDecode.Trim();
                sum += Convert.ToInt32(columnValueDecode);
            }

        }            
        // Display the summary data in the appropriate cells
        e.Row.Cells[j].Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
```

Comment: Whats the value of `grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text` when you are reading the date cell?

Comment: 450&#160;000 after `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` is 450 000

Comment: Why not use the source data instead of converting between string and int. That is bound to cause problems (as your qestion is proof of that)

Comment: I have datasource in view. Converting GridView to DataTable i think make the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer:

```
string columnValueDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
    columnValueDecode = Regex.Replace(columnValueDecode, @"\s+", "");
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(columnValueDecode);
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (!grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Equals("&nbsp;"))
{
    string columnValueDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
    columnValueDecode.Replace(" ", "");
    columnValueDecode.Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
    columnValueDecode.Trim();
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(columnValueDecode);
}
```

to

```
if (!grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Equals("&nbsp;"))
{
    string columnValueDecode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(grid_summary.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
    columnValueDecode = columnValueDecode.Trim().Replace(" ", "").Replace("\t", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
    sum += Convert.ToInt32(columnValueDecode);
}
```

In fact, it is safer to do these operations on the grid data source.

Comment: I can not do `columnValueDecode.Trim().columnValueDecode.Replace(" ", "").(...)` string does not have definition for columnValueDecode

Comment: sorry, I Updated answer.